# Xcode 8.2 give broken code for NSManagedObject subclass

Tags: swift

Latest xcode version 8.2 , generates the broken NSManagedObject subclass code.

Here is the solution,

1. Select your model file eg Model.xcdatamodel
2. Click "show the file inspector" which is first tab at the right side.
3. change the Tool version to xcode 7.3
4. Doing all these three step, then only try to make the subclass of your entity. This time xcode will not give any kind of error.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the above solution not work then please follow these below steps, well you can consider these steps as final.

1. First delete the auto generated .xcdatamodel file
2. Add the new data model file from the template (hope you know how to do that in the same way as you do to add new files, in the same manner you can also add the data model file).
3. Once the data model file is added  click on it, then go to the first tab (show the file inspector)at the right side, below there select the minimum Tool version to xcode 7.3.
4. Now before creating the NSManagedObject Subclass, select your entity first and then click the third tab (show the Data model inspector), there you have to change the codegen to Manual/None.
5. Now you are ready to generate the NSManagedObject Subclass..

This time xcode will not show the errors.

Thanks, hope this helps.